# Можно ли не ставить пробел между функцией и аргументом?

Tags: haskell, language-lawyer, грамматика

Можно ли вызывать функцию с каким-то аргументом без пробела между ними?

```hs
main=putStr"test"
```

Например, такой код компилируется. Пытался посмотреть в https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010, но не смог найти правило, разрешающее это.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется, понял. Никто не запрещает не ставить пробел в соответствии с грамматикой:

```
program →   { lexeme | whitespace }
lexeme  →   qvarid | qconid | qvarsym | qconsym
|   literal | special | reservedop | reservedid
literal →   integer | float | char | string
```

Т.е. программа `putStr "test"` это лексемы `putStr` и `"test"` + whitespace  . Но можно использовать и просто лексемы `putStr` и `"test"` без пробела, т.к. `{` означет 0+, а `|` - ИЛИ.